# Calling superclass method AsyncTask.execute() on anonymous object new HttpRequestTask<...> extends AsyncTask<...>

Tags: java, android, inheritance, android-asynctask, anonymous-types

I have problem when creating an anonymous object and calling a function implemented in a superclass.

AsyncTask

```
public abstract class AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>{
    protected abstract Result doInBackground(Params... params);

    public final AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> execute(Params... params) {
        //implementation. Shortly, it calls doInBackground(params).
    }
}
```

HttpRequestTask

```
public abstract class HttpRequestTask<T> extends AsyncTask<String, Void, AsyncTaskResult<ResponseEntity<T>>>{
    @Override
    protected AsyncTaskResult<ResponseEntity<T>> doInBackground(String... url) {
        //implementation
    }

    //...create other abstract methods (no relation with the question)...

    public HttpRequestTask authenticate(SharedPreferences authPreferences) {
        this.authPreferences = authPreferences;
        return this;
    }
}
```

And I use the classes like this:

```
new HttpRequestTask<Player, Void>(Player.class) {
    //...implementation of abstract methods from HttpRequestTask
}
    .authenticate(authPreferences)
    .execute("any string");
```

Running this, I get this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.String[]
    at com.edu.antechamber.controller.HttpRequestTask.doInBackground(HttpRequestTask.java:41)
```

Where line 41 is: `public abstract class HttpRequestTask<T> extends AsyncTask<String, Void, AsyncTaskResult<ResponseEntity<T>>>`

I should say that the code in `doInBackground()` is not executed because the exception appears before the first line is executed.

I think the issue comes when I create the anonymous object `new HttpRequestTask<Player, Void>(Player.class) {...}`, call `authenticate(...)`, this returns this (the anonymous objet), and call `execute("any string")`. `execute()` should call `doInBackground("any string")`, but I think it calls doInBackground with some `Object` instead.

Android Studio gives me this warning:

```
Unchecked Call to 'execute(Params…)' as a member of raw type 'android.os.AsyncTask'
```

If I remove the `.authenticate(authPreferences)` part, there shouldn't make any difference because `authenticate()` returns `this`, but counterintuitively everything works fine again.

In the same way, if I initialize `authPreferences` in `HttpRequestTask`'s constructor, it works again. But I really need to get the `authenticate()` function working, otherwise I would have a lot of constructors.

I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me in solving this problem.

Comment: Please show the code around HttpRequestTask.java:41

Comment: I've edited the question, line 41 is `public abstract class HttpRequestTask<T> extends AsyncTask<String, Void, AsyncTaskResult<ResponseEntity<T>>>`

Comment: Shouldnt it be `public HttpRequestTask<T> authenticate(SharedPreferences authPreferences)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it can be solved by passing an array

```
execute(new String[]{"/api/player/55707e1eb7396de50dcef73d"})
```

instead of one String argument

```
execute("/api/player/55707e1eb7396de50dcef73d")
```

the issue is at this line, instead of

```
public HttpRequestTask authenticate(SharedPreferences authPreferences)
```

like @user says, it should be

```
public HttpRequestTask<T> authenticate(SharedPreferences authPreferences)
```

Thank you very much!